# In Rails, how to I redirect to an external url and stay in my iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, iframe

I have a web app nested in an iframe. When I do a

```
redirect_to(url)
```

it opens the page in a new tab. I want to redirect/navigate to a page within my iframe.

I originally added

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
    'X-Content-Type-Options' => 'nosniff',
   'X-XSS-Protection' => '1;'
}
```

to environments/development.rb which loaded the initial app in the iframe, but it does not seem to help with the redirect.

Comment: if the action is triggered through some form you can use target attribute in form to set where the response to be rendered(i.e. within the tab or in a new tab) ideally it shouldn't open up a new tab to render the response for the action. Post the html markup for the iframe